# Counter visible items on page and update when user clicks load more js

Tags: javascript

Hi so I kind of got this working. So right now it displays count as 12 by default which is correct but when I click load more the counter doesn't update to reflect 24 items are visible if I click load more a second time it says 24 when it should be 36 by that point. I also wanted to display total amount regardless if div class was hidden or not. example 12 of 40.

https://codepen.io/nufftalon/pen/eYRgxeY

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  function articlecount() {
    var count = $(".content:visible").length;
    $("#count").html("Count : " + count);
  }

  $(".content").slice(0, 12).show();
  articlecount();
  $("#loadMore").on("click", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    articlecount();

    $(".content:hidden").slice(0, 12).slideDown();
    if ($(".content:hidden").length == 0) {
      $("#loadMore").text("No Content").addClass("noContent");
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're updating the `count` value *before* showing the new records.  Update it *after*:

```
// show the records
$(".content:hidden").slice(0, 12).slideDown();
if ($(".content:hidden").length == 0) {
  $("#loadMore").text("No Content").addClass("noContent");
}

// update the count
articlecount();
```

Comment: Was messing with this for too long haha thanks that did the trick!